# Simple pubsub with jQuery

Tags: jquery, publish-subscribe

Is there any reason why it would be against best practice to use jQuery's `trigger` and `on` methods as a cheap and easy pubsub?

The following works:

```
$(document).on('my:custom:event',function(){
    alert('this is an event');
});
```

And later:

```
$(document).trigger('my:custom:event');
//=> alerts
```

Obviously [a real jQuery pubsub plugin](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/661855) would be **trivial** to install - I'm really looking to see:

- Are there any hidden caveats?
- Is this acceptable to get away with in StackOverflow examples to demonstrate event-driven behavior without confusing the OP by including some plugin code?

Comment: Would be great as an answer as it address the 'caveats' section.

Comment: The second part of your question should be asked in http://meta.stackoverflow.com (although I believe it was already asked before - so you might want to look for it).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum No other answers have been posted - go ahead and leave your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your use case is simple enough - go right ahead:

You can use it on arbitrary objects

```
var obj = {};$(obj).on(...) .
```

Note that if you're using it on the document, you're effectively creating a global hidden dependency. Also, rolling your own pubsub for the client-side is ~20 LoC so that's another consideration since a jQuery dependency isn't something you'd always want to have.